# Mock Unit Test Case For Spring jdbc template for RowMapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, java-8

I am trying to test with Junit for my StudentRowmapper class, I am a bit new for Unit Test and also Mock test, I have asked smilar question before, but I could not figure out how to mock Datetime.of object. When I run my test; DateTimes throws null pointer exception

StudentGroupList below;

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class StudentGroupList {
    
     private String studentId;
     private LocalDateTime studentDate();
    }
```

StudentGroupListRowMapper below;

```
public class StudentGroupListRowMapper implements RowMapper<StudentGroupList> {

  @Override
  public StudentGroupList mapRow(Resultset rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

  StudentGroupList studentGroupList = new StudentGroupList();
 
  studentGroupList.setStudentId(rs.getString("student_id"));
  studentGroupList.setStudentDate(rs.getTimestamp("student_date").toLocalDateTime());

  return studentGroupList;
 }
}
```

My Unit Test below;

```
private static int rowNum = 2;
  private StudentGroupListRowMapper mapper;
  private ResultSet resultSet;
  private StudentGroupList studentGroupList;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
   studentGroupList = new StudentGroupList();
   mapper = new StudentGroupListRowMapper();
   resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
 }
  

     @Test
     public void testmapRow() throws SQLException {
    
     when(resultSet.getString("student_id")).thenReturn("sutdent-id-1");
     when(resultSet.getTimeStamp("student_date").toLocalDateTime()).thenReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2001,3,17,2,10)));
    
    studentGroupList mapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNum);
    
    assertEquals(studentGroupList .getStudentId(), "sutdent-id-1");
    assertEquals(studentGroupList .getStudentDate, LocalDateTime.of(2001,3,17,2,10)); 
     
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static int rowNum = 2;
  @InjectMocks
  private StudentGroupListRowMapper mapper;
  @Mock
  private ResultSet resultSet;
  @Mock
  private StudentGroupList studentGroupList;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    studentGroupList = new StudentGroupList();
    mapper = new StudentGroupListRowMapper();
    resultSet = createResultSet();
  }

  createResultSet(){
  resultSet = new ResultSet();
  resultSet.setStudentId(111);
  resultSet.setStudentId(LocalDateTime.of(2001,3,17,2,10));
  }
  

  @Test
  public void testmapRow() throws SQLException {
   
  studentGroupList = mapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNum);
   
  asserThat(studentGroupList.getStudentId()).isEqualTo(110);
  asserThat(studentGroupList.getStudentId()).isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2001,3,17,2,10));  
     
  }
```

I suggest you convert String student id to an int or parse the string. I just used an integer. From what I could gather, this is my solution for you. Hope you could understand the structure of the test. There are more ways to do this

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have used and leave my test class exactly same but nothing has changed.